# Django retrieve checkbox values sent by Ajax POST request

Tags: html, django

I am trying to send form data to Django server via Javascript Ajax request specifically checkbox values, but at the server I read None values. here's the server code that reads:

```
@csrf_protect
def order_pizza(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        topps = Topping.objects.all()
        for topp in topps:
            mytop = request.POST.getlist('topping')
            print(f"topp is {topp.__str__()} mytop is {mytop}")
    return HttpResponse("pizza order!!")
```

And here's the html for the form:

```
<form id="form_pizza_order" class="form_pizza_order" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="order_topp_col col-12">
            <header> Topping </header>
            {% for topp in toppings %}
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ topp.name }}"  name="topping" value="{{ topp.name }}">
            <label for="{{ topp.name }}"> {{topp.name}}</label>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
...
```

the print function returns a result :

```
topp is Pepperoni mytop is []
topp is Sausage mytop is []
topp is Mushrooms mytop is []
topp is Onions mytop is []
topp is Ham mytop is []
etc ...
```

what do I have to do to be able to read the checkboxes values ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in javascript sending form data to server.

I used `const FD = new FormData();`

now I realized should have used:

```
  let myform = document.getElementById("form_pizza_order");
    const FD = new FormData(myform);
```

now the data is populated to the server.